# Exclude round rectangle from clipping region?

Tags: windows, delphi, gdi

What's the correct way to exclude a round rectangle from the clipping gregion with Delphi  / GDI?

There is [ExcludeClipRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx1) to exclude a rectangular region and there is [CreateRoundRectRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) together with [SelectClipRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the clipping region to a round rectangle.

But how can I **exclude** a round rectange from the clipping region (something like ExcludeClipRoundRect or ExcludeClipRgn)? I experimented with [CombineRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but did not get it working.

Comment: Have you tried [`RGN_XOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RGN_XOR) combine mode ? Btw. quite a good tutorial is [`e.g. here`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1944/Guide-to-WIN32-Regions).

Comment: @TLama - To *exclude* a region, you want `RGN_DIFF`. But it won't matter here since the excluded region is fully inside.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the comment by @TLama I was able to solve it like this:

```
Region := CreateRectRgn (0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
ExcludedRegion := CreateRoundRectRgn (1, 1, ClientWidth - 1, ClientHeight - 1, 3, 3);
CombineRgn (Region, Region, ExcludedRegion, RGN_XOR);
SelectClipRgn (Canvas.Handle, Region);
```

The problem before was that the region passed as the first parameter to `CombineRgn` has not been created. One sentence from the linked tutorial provided the clue:

> One more thing to point out is that the destination region in
>   CombineRgn can be one of the source regions.

together with this information from MSDN:

> hrgnDest [in]: A handle to a new region with dimensions defined by combining two
>   other regions. (This region must exist before CombineRgn is called.)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the already [given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19903565/243614), which will allow to define one less region, is to use [`ExtSelectClipRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
ExcludedRegion := CreateRoundRectRgn (1, 1, ClientWidth - 1, ClientHeight - 1, 3, 3);
ExtSelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, ExcludedRegion, RGN_DIFF);
```

If you're not sure that the clipping region has been unmodified before or not, and want to reset the region, you can call

```
SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, 0);
```

before calling `ExtSelectClipRgn`.